# How to run gradle automated suite parallel in multiple thread?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, gradle, automation, cucumber

we have automated regression suite but to simplify we want to run our cucumber BDD tests in parallel with multi thread atleast 2. We use gradle so is it possible to do something with gradle.

If something is unclear please let me know

Thank You

Comment: Please see this thread where Pieter Niederwasser chimes in on the same topic. http://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-you-run-multiple-javaexec-tasks-in-parallel/7309/2 "
He says:
It isn't currently possible to run multiple tasks in the same project in parallel, but you can write a task that internally spawns multiple threads (e.g. as shown in the post above) and uses the 'javaexec' method instead.

Comment: But then, he also posted "As for the Cucumber tests, I thought that the worst problems have been sorted out and that they can now be run with Gradle's regular 'test' task (as JUnit tests). If that's the case, then you just need to set 'test.maxParallelForks = n'."

Comment: Thanks Jolta for directing me to this post. I will try if that works